# sqlite : Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_escape_string()

Tags: php, database, sqlite, fatal-error

I use a script who recquires SQLITE,

on my previous hoster, it works,
on local it works,

on my new dedicaced server, it doesn't, i use PHP5 of course, on this link, you have a phpinfo() of the server.
http://bit.ly/bXlLT1

Could you tell me what/how (apt get?) to install correctly sqlite to avoid this fatal error?
Thanks

Comment: Does the server also have PECL sqlite >= 1.0.0 installed? Have you tried to Google something like "PECL sqlite package"? Someone on http://serverfault.com would probably be able to help you better with packages.

Comment: http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php  ----> As of PHP 5 this extension is enabled by default, so simply do not disable it and it'll be available.   ----> i didn't disabled it =o

Comment: you're right, i posted on serveurfault, it's more appropriate thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sqlite installed : problem fixed.